# 80:12: Error: Can't return a value from a void function

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
List<Service> getListServices() {
  CollectionReference services =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Services");
  Map<String, dynamic> doc;
  Timer timer;
  const towSec = Duration(seconds: 2);
  Image image;
  List<Service> listServices = [];
  List<Image> pictures;
  int price;

  services.where("geolocalisation", isEqualTo: const GeoPoint(1, 1)).get().then(
      (value) => {
            for (var docs in value.docs)
              {
                doc = docs.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
                price = 2,
                image = Image.asset("assets/images/logo.ong"),
                pictures = [image],
                listServices.add(Service(doc["name"], doc["name"],
                    doc["description"], pictures, price, const GeoPoint(1, 1))),
              },
          },
      onError: (error) => print(error));
  timer = Timer.periodic(towSec, (timer) {
    print("in get list service function");
    print(listServices.length); //length == 1
    timer.cancel();
    return listServices;
  });
}
```

i expect the function to return a list with one item on it
i tried to put the return outside but it return an empty list of services

Comment: `f() => x` is shorthand for `f() { return x; }`.  Therefore `=> { ... }` returns a `Set` literal.  If you want the braces to denote a function body, remove the `=>`.

Comment: Additionally, nothing waits for your `Future` or `Timer` to complete, so your `getListServices` function fails to return a `List<Service>`.  Instead make your function `async` and `await` any `Future`s.  It's also not clear why you make a periodic `Timer` that you immediately cancel the first time it's triggered.  If you want to wait for a fixed amount of time, use `await Future.delayed(towSec);`.